# Moving from Finitely Additive to Countably Additive

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I have a question on basic measure theory here:

> Let $(X, \mathscr A)$ be measurable space and $\mu$ is a non-negative set function that is *finitely additive* and such that $\mu (\emptyset) = 0$. *Suppose that whenever $A_i$ is an increasing sequence of sets in $\mathscr A$, then $\mu(\cup_i A_i) = \lim_{i \to \infty} \mu(A_i)$.* Show that $\mu$ is a measure.

Here are the questions I would like you to help:

(1) First, background question: In this problem, "finitely additive" means
$$\mu(\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j) = \sum_{j=1}^n \mu(A_j), \quad \text{where }A_j \text{'s are pairwisely disjoint.}$$
Correct me if I am wrong here.

(2) Another background: The phrase "Suppose that whenever $A_i$ is an increasing sequence of sets..." means

$$\text{if } A_i \uparrow \text{ then } \mu(\cup_i A_i) = \lim_{i \to \infty} \mu(A_i), \quad \text{where } \ldots A_{i-1}\subset A_i \subset A_{i+1} \ldots$$
Again, correct me if I am wrong here.

(3) Done with the background. To solve this problem, my understanding is to "move" from *finitely additive* as given in (1) to *countably additive* as given in a measure's definition, but I do not how to proceed. Do please let me know the friendliest way of solving this problem.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Yes.

(2) "Suppose that whenever $A_i$ is an increasing sequence of sets..." means $A_i \nearrow$, i.e., $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots$.

(3) To show $\mu$ is a measure, you need to show two things:

1. $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$
2. If $A_i \in \mathcal A$, $i = 1, 2, \ldots$ are pairwise disjoing, then $$\mu\bigg( \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i \bigg) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \mu(A_i).$$

We know it holds for the finite case by hypothesis, i.e., replace $\infty$ by $n \in \mathbb N$. You now need to show it holds for $\infty$.

---

**Proof**: 
Observe that $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ by hypothesis.

Let $\{A_k\}$ be a collection of disjoint measurable sets.

Define $B_n = \bigcup_{k = 1}^n A_k$.

Notice that $B_n \nearrow \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty A_k$ is an increasing sequence of sets in $\mathcal A$.

Observe that

\begin{align*}
\mu \bigg( \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty B_n \bigg) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(B_n) \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu \bigg( \sum_{k = 1}^n A_k \bigg) \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n \mu(A_k) \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mu(A_k)
\end{align*}

Conclude by definition that $\mu$ is a measure.

Comment: Thanks as always. So there is different meaning between the up-arrow $\uparrow$ and the northeast arrow $\nearrow$ on (2)?

Comment: No, they're the same thing! Saying you have an increasing sequence just means: $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq A_3 \subseteq \cdots$. It doesn't mean the implication you wrote in (2). You are **given** that as a hypothesis: when you have such an increasing sequence, then that limit property follows; now use it.

Comment: Thanks again. I haven't finished digesting yours but I had always positive experience whenever you jumped in to my help.

Comment: Feel free to ask for clarifications!

Comment: I am done, thanks for your patient step-by-step analysis, have up-voted and green checked. Thank you! One non-math question, if you will: How do you make the light line just right before the proof? Thanks again.

Comment: @A.Magnus 10 dashes will do it.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to turn a countable disjoint union into an increasing union. To do that, you'll need to use different sets. So suppose $\{ A_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a disjoint collection of measurable sets. Consider $\{ B_m \}_{m=1}^\infty$ defined by $B_m = \bigcup_{n=1}^m A_n$. This is an increasing union, so it has the limit property which was assumed. Use this to conclude the limit property you want for the measure of the union of the $A_n$.

Comment: Before digesting your idea: Do my understandings on (1) and (2) are correct? Notice that the index in (1) and (2) are $j$ and $i$ respectively, so they are different. Let me know. Thanks again.